# Generate a random number with max, min and mean (average) in visual basics - triangular dist

Tags: vba, random, distribution

I am looking to see how I can create a triangular distribution using 3 numbers of minimum (40) maximum (330) and average (100).

this code just give me the random between 2 numbers and does not carry the average :

```
 z = =RAND()*(b-a)+a
```

How can I make it a triangular dist. ?

Comment: You can't generate a triangle distribution with the three values you've given.  You specify that the mean is supposed to be 100, and `mean = (min + max + mode) / 3`.  Given your specifications, solving for the mode in `100 = (40 + 330 + mode) / 3` yields a value of -70, which is not between the min and max.

Comment: @pjs 100 is the average (mean). I think you made a mistake in calculating the mean. I have already given it.

Comment: No mistake, you said you want a minimum of 40, maximum of 330, and average (mean) of 100.  [The mean of a triangular distribution **is** `mean = (min + max + mode) / 3`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution), so we can calculate what the mode would have to be.  Your numbers are infeasible for a triangular distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected as per @Severin Pappadeux

```
Function trigDist(dMIn As Double, dMax As Double, dMean As Double) As Double

    Dim dFR         As Double
    Dim bProceed    As Boolean

    bProceed = True

    '/ error checks               

    If dMIn >= dMax Then
        MsgBox "max value less than min value."
        bProceed = False
    End If

    If dMean < dMIn Then
        MsgBox "Mean is less than min value."
         bProceed = False
    End If

    If dMean > dMax Then
        MsgBox "Mean is larger than max value."
         bProceed = False
    End If


    If bProceed Then

        dFR = Rnd()

        If dFR < ((dMean - dMIn) / (dMax - dMIn)) Then
            trigDist = Sqr(dFR * (dMean - dMIn) * (dMax - dMIn)) + dMIn
        Else
            trigDist = dMax - Sqr((1 - dFR) * (dMax - dMean) * (dMax - dMIn))
        End If
    Else

       trigDist = 0
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I was wondering 1. What is the dFR ? 2. Why sqr has been used in the formula?

Comment: It gives the run time error 5 : Invalid procedure call of argument when I changed the numbers of min, max and average.

Comment: having min: 40 , max: 150 and average:90 gives me that error.

Comment: @cyboashu you're wrong, input is `min`, `max` and `mean`, not a, b, c.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux You are right about the inputs. Could you please provide the correct code?

Comment: @Zapata you could check my answer, though it is not tested in any way - have no VBA tools right now.

Comment: @cyboashu It does not work. I think the previous code was closer to the right answer. Since I have already given the mean (average) there is no need to calculate it.

Comment: @cyboashu I have run-time error '5': invalid procedure call or argument when I give the numbers like this ( min:50 , max : 300 and mean/average: 180).

Comment: i am getting the value.... 197.285397419811.... How are you calling the function??

Comment: For i = 3 To 528

    Worksheets("ACTlite").Cells(i, "AA").Value = trigDist(41, 336, 60) ' triangular distribution

    next i

Comment: You are doing something wrong test `msgbox trigDist(50, 300, 180)` it will confirm the function is correct. Now as per yuour call, you need to have a Worksheet named `A`, and  a valid value for `i` . Check what are you ding wrong.

Comment: @cyboashu

Private Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 500
Debug.Print trigDist(50, 300, 180)
Next i
End Sub


Gave me the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117734/discussion-between-zapata-and-cyboashu).

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, answer by @cyboashu is wrong, because you have `Min`, `Max` and `Mean`.

So you start with recovering A, B, C from input, using the fact from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) that mean is equal to `(A+B+C)/3`. Don't know enough VBA, so bear with me

```
A = Min
B = Max
C = 3.0*Mean - A - B

If A >= B Then
    print 'Error, Min is greater than Max'
End If

If C < A Then
    print 'Error, Mean is too small'
End If

If C > B Then
    print 'Error, Mean is too large'
End If

r = Rnd()

If r < ((C - A) / (B - A)) Then
    Res = A + Sqr(r * (B - A) * (C - A))
Else
    Res = B - Sqr((1.0 - r) * (B - A) * (B - C))
End If

return Res
```

Comment: @Severin Pappadeux it does not work. Why did you calculate the mean while I have already given it as the average number (100)?

Comment: @Severin Pappadeux  tahnks for all the mathematical guidance. +1

Comment: @Zapata ? Where did I calculate the mean?! Min, Max and Mean are input and assumed to be given. From (Min, Max, Mean) troika I compute (A,B,C) as required by all formulas in Triangular Distribution, and use them for sampling.